# Prevent duplicate pugixml::xml_node

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I'm writing a part of my app that store settings in XML file, but I don't want to 'client' duplicate, I want this:

```
<jack>
  <client name="something">
    <port name="someport" />
    <port name="someport_2" />
  </client>
</jack>
```

But instead I get:

```
<jack>
  <client name="something">
    <port name="someport" />
  </client>
  <client name="something">
    <port name="someport_2" />
  </client>
</jack>
```

thought "just check if node already exists" but that's the problem, so I've this piece of code:

```
// xjack is the root node
pugi::xml_node xclient = xjack.child(sclient.c_str());
if (!xclient) {
    xclient = xjack.append_child("client");
}
```

but `!xclient` always evaluate to true, tried also `if (xclient.empty())` but not work also.

Comment: How is sclient initialized?

Comment: It's initialized within a loop that is result of another string substr, `sclient = client->first.substr(0, client->first.find(':'));` client->first is a string in format "something:someport"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thinking about the comments zeuxcg I could figure out what was wrong.

`pugi::xml_node xclient = xjack.child(sclient.c_str());` is looking up for a child with name "something" that really doesn't exists, what I'm looking for is a tag with name "client" and attribute "name" with value of "something".

So, the correct is:

```
pugi::xml_node xclient = xjack.find_child_by_attribute("client", "name", sclient.c_str());
if (!xclient) {
    xclient = xjack.append_child("client");
    xclient.append_attribute("name").set_value(sclient.c_str());
}
```